# Add "Class" option in the New menu in Java EE perspective

Tags: java, eclipse

I am almost always using the Java EE perspective in eclipse. However each time I need to add a class I have to do New > Other > Class

Is there a way to customize the New Menu shown for a perspective so that I have New Class option right in that menu (only 2 clicks away)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the 'Customize Perspective' dialog to do this ('Window > Customize Perspective' or 'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective' depending on your Eclipse release).

Choose the 'Shortcuts' tab. Choose the 'New' submenu (normally the default anyway). Click on the 'Java' category and choose 'Class' (and anything else you want) in the shortcuts section

[image]

Comment: Thanks! - had never seen this, couldnt find anything under Preferences

Answer (score 2):

You can customize your menu using the "Customize Perspective" option.

On the menu bar click

```
Window -> Customize Perspective
```

In that menu you have the ability to specify all your defaults for your perspective. For your situation you can go to

```
Menu Visibility -> File -> New
```

And then select 'Class' as one of your items to display in the new submenu. You can also deselect ones you never use!